# Unix - Awk - Matching & Merging Two Files on A Partial Match (Within Character String)

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two text files: FileA.txt and FileB.txt.

They are tab-delimited.
FileA.txt contains transaction-level records.
FileB.txt contains a reference/ lookup "table".

I would like to append columns called "Company" and "CATEGORY" in FileB.txt to FileA.txt by matching the contents of "Company" in FileB.txt to "Description" in FileA.txt.

To clarify, match & merge should be on the basis of whether or not the contents for "Company" exist within the character string contained in column called "Description" in FileA.txt .
Any assistance on this would be appreciated.

FileA.txt

```
Date    Description Amount
1/15/2016   1231 HAMBURGER #1234 Albany NY 24186166001200699400511  -22.54
3/3/2016    EASTERN FRUIT CO S1 Trenton NJ  -110.93
2/26/2016   GUMPS* PAPER INC. 999-123-4560 CA   -9.99
2/16/2016   EASY BURGERS SUPPLIES 01/31 #000741643 PURCHASE FOOD S TRENTON NJ   -10.97
2/19/2016   FRANKFURTER Stamford CT -14.18
2/5/2016    CHECKCARD 0141FRANK'S GROCERIES Albany NY 24071056031987159327565   -87.92
3/11/2016   WIRED PENCIL & PAPER Sacramento NJ  -72.16
3/18/2016   UNDERWATER MAIL SRVC 654321 800-1234567 DC  -65
1/31/2016   VOYAGER REAL ESTATE CO . 415 DES:LEASE PYMNT INDN:123 Main St. CO ID:XXXXX999 ACH   -126.65
1/18/2016   CARD 0101 US BASKETWEAVING ASSOC 123-456-7890 TX 54692166432112345  -265
4/18/2016   CARD ACH #89 UNDERWATER MAIL SRVC 654321 800-1234567 DC 6787654320  -250
```

FileB.txt

```
Company CATEGORY
HAMBURGER   FOOD
FRANKFURTER FOOD
PAPER INC.  OFFICE
WIRED PENCIL & PAPER    OFFICE
FRANK'S GROCERIES   GROC
EASY BURGERS SUPPLIES   GROC
EASTERN FRUIT CO.   GROC
US BASKETWEAVING ASSOC  OFFICE
UNDERWATER MAIL SRVC    OFFICE
VOYAGER REAL ESTATE REAL ESTATE
```

Comment: can you format your input?

Comment: Approximately how many lines in `FileB.txt` (10s, 100s, 1000s, 1000000s)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation. Not sure that awk is the best tool.

```
  awk -F '\t' '
    BEGIN {
        while(getline < "fileB.txt")
           fileB[$1]=$0
    }

    {
      matched=""
      for (company in fileB) 
      {    
        if ( $2 ~  company ) 
        {
            matched=fileB[company]
            break
        }
      } 
      if (matched)
        print $0 "\t" matched
      else
        print 

    }' fileA.txt
```

This is to show you how to start, that script can be improved.
Matching is reliable only if the input is clean, otherwise it will not work. 
beware of upper/lower case, words separated by more than one space, ... 
It is possible that a line will match more than one company, that script will not detect it, in that case you would have to replace the break by a counter then test after the loop.